# NHibernate 3 and LINQ support?

Tags: linq, nhibernate

Just wanted to know if NHibernate 3 have full linq support yet ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as "full" LINQ support.

LINQ to anything except Objects is a leaky abstraction. Some operations that are trivial to express in an object model are hard to translate to SQL, and vice-versa.

That said, the LINQ provider in NH3 is quite usable, and a lot of work is being put into it (a lot of that will be visible in the 3.0.1 release, which will be out around 28/Feb/2011)

The good news is with NH you always have alternatives. If you can't do a particular query with LINQ, there's always HQL, Criteria, QueryOver and even SQL. They all integrate nicely with the rest of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

No there are still some [unsupported features](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/dbceb7eb1e31f027/f8e69671b750e0d6?lnk=gst&q=NotSupportedException+stefan#f8e69671b750e0d6). It's not a full LINQ implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have full linq support because it is too much (impossible much) work to write a full link provider. I don't think any full linq provider exists.

You can find the currently unsupported features in Jira.